# How to repeat this structure in the views.py?

Tags: python, django, loops, python-2.7, django-views

I'm new to python and am using the [python-weather-api](https://code.google.com/p/python-weather-api/). I'm trying to get this JSON structure into a `list` (this is the name that I know in Java, sorry if isn't).

```
'forecasts': [   {   'code': u'34',
                         'date': u'27 Mar 2013',
                         'day': u'Wed',
                         'high': u'9',
                         'low': u'2',
                         'text': u'Mostly Sunny'},
                     {   'code': u'28',
                         'date': u'28 Mar 2013',
                         'day': u'Thu',
                         'high': u'10',
                         'low': u'2',
                         'text': u'Mostly Cloudy'},
                     {   'code': u'30',
                         'date': u'29 Mar 2013',
                         'day': u'Fri',
                         'high': u'11',
                         'low': u'3',
                         'text': u'Partly Cloudy'},
                     {   'code': u'30',
                         'date': u'30 Mar 2013',
                         'day': u'Sat',
                         'high': u'11',
                         'low': u'3',
                         'text': u'Partly Cloudy'},
                     {   'code': u'28',
                         'date': u'31 Mar 2013',
                         'day': u'Sun',
                         'high': u'10',
                         'low': u'7',
                         'text': u'Mostly Cloudy'}],
```

To get access to the first value for example I'm doing this:

```
forecast = {
      'day_0': yahoo_result['forecasts'][0]['day'],
}
```

This is what I'm doing now:

```
views.py
  forecast = {
          'day_0': yahoo_result['forecasts'][0]['day'],
          'text_0': yahoo_result['forecasts'][0]['text'],
          'high_0': yahoo_result['forecasts'][0]['high'],
          'low_0': yahoo_result['forecasts'][0]['low'],

          'day_1': yahoo_result['forecasts'][1]['day'],
          'text_1': yahoo_result['forecasts'][1]['text'],
          'high_1': yahoo_result['forecasts'][1]['high'],
          'low_1': yahoo_result['forecasts'][1]['low'],

          'day_2': yahoo_result['forecasts'][2]['day'],
          'text_2': yahoo_result['forecasts'][2]['text'],
          'high_2': yahoo_result['forecasts'][2]['high'],
          'low_2': yahoo_result['forecasts'][2]['low'],

          'day_3': yahoo_result['forecasts'][3]['day'],
          'text_3': yahoo_result['forecasts'][3]['text'],
          'high_3': yahoo_result['forecasts'][3]['high'],
          'low_3': yahoo_result['forecasts'][3]['low'],

          'day_4': yahoo_result['forecasts'][4]['day'],
          'text_4': yahoo_result['forecasts'][4]['text'],
          'high_4': yahoo_result['forecasts'][4]['high'],
          'low_4': yahoo_result['forecasts'][4]['low'],

    }

return render(request, 'index.html', {'weather':weather, 'forecast': forecast})
```

And displaying the result in the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <ul>
        <li> <!-- start the loop right here -->
            <h2>{{ forecast.day_0 }}</h2>
            <i class=" ico-cloudy text-primary"></i>
            <div class="statistics"> low {{ forecast.low_0 }}</div>
            <div class="statistics"> high {{ forecast.high_0 }}</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>{{ forecast.day_1 }}</h2>
            <i class=" ico-cloudy text-primary"></i>
            <div class="statistics"> low {{ forecast.low_1 }}</div>
            <div class="statistics"> high {{ forecast.high_1 }}</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>{{ forecast.day_2 }}</h2>
            <i class=" ico-cloudy text-primary"></i>
            <div class="statistics"> low {{ forecast.low_2 }}</div>
            <div class="statistics"> high {{ forecast.high_2 }}</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>{{ forecast.day_3 }}</h2>
            <i class=" ico-cloudy text-primary"></i>
            <div class="statistics"> low {{ forecast.low_3 }}</div>
            <div class="statistics"> high {{ forecast.high_3 }}</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>{{ forecast.day_4 }}</h2>
            <i class=" ico-cloudy text-primary"></i>
            <div class="statistics"> low {{ forecast.low_4 }}</div>
            <div class="statistics"> high {{ forecast.high_4 }}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I would like to put this whole structure in a list to be able to loop in the HTML file after, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `yahoo_result['forecasts']` seems to be a list, have you tried this :

In your view :

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'weather':weather, 'forecast': yahoo_result['forecasts']})
```

In your template file :

```
<ul>
    {% for item in forecast %}
        <li>
            <h2>{{ item.day }}</h2>
            <i class="ico-cloudy text-primary"></i>
            <div class="statistics"> low {{ item.low }}</div>
            <div class="statistics"> high {{ item.high }}</div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Let me give a try on that :)

Comment: no problem, for more information about django for loop in template you can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) and for python data types [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datatypes.html)